# w64-Mingw LLVMSupport.a : undefined reference to __imp_*

Tags: linker, static-libraries, llvm

Quite weird bug trying to link something to LLVMSupport :

```
C:/projects/builds/LLVM-3.3/lib/../lib/libLLVMsupport.a(Signals.cpp.obj):Signals.cpp:(.text+0x524): undefined reference to `__imp_SymSetOptions'
C:/projects/builds/LLVM-3.3/lib/../lib/libLLVMsupport.a(Signals.cpp.obj):Signals.cpp:(.text+0x542): undefined reference to `__imp_SymInitialize'
C:/projects/builds/LLVM-3.3/lib/../lib/libLLVMsupport.a(Signals.cpp.obj):Signals.cpp:(.text+0x576): undefined reference to `__imp_SymGetModuleBase64'
C:/projects/builds/LLVM-3.3/lib/../lib/libLLVMsupport.a(Signals.cpp.obj):Signals.cpp:(.text+0x582): undefined reference to `__imp_SymFunctionTableAccess64'
C:/projects/builds/LLVM-3.3/lib/../lib/libLLVMsupport.a(Signals.cpp.obj):Signals.cpp:(.text+0x5a1): undefined reference to `__imp_StackWalk64'
C:/projects/builds/LLVM-3.3/lib/../lib/libLLVMsupport.a(Signals.cpp.obj):Signals.cpp:(.text+0x644): undefined reference to `__imp_SymGetModuleBase64'
C:/projects/builds/LLVM-3.3/lib/../lib/libLLVMsupport.a(Signals.cpp.obj):Signals.cpp:(.text+0x6f4): undefined reference to `__imp_SymGetSymFromAddr64'
C:/projects/builds/LLVM-3.3/lib/../lib/libLLVMsupport.a(Signals.cpp.obj):Signals.cpp:(.text+0x7d9): undefined reference to `__imp_SymGetLineFromAddr64'
```

there are functions with similar names in dbghelp.dll
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681327%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

but linking to this lib doesn't fix it.

I've been on this problem for a while... How to fix it ?

Note : 
I've compiled llvm with cmake + mingw64 in 64 bits with SEH with a patch to force a correct EH method test.

Then I can't find where these symbols are used...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MinGW comes with its own implementation, just to add -limagehlp at the end (the order matters) of the command