# Undefined references while building LLVM with MinGW-w64

Tags: c++, llvm, mingw-w64, undefined-reference

I am trying to build LLVM using MinGW-w64 (GCC 8.1.0). After `cmake .. -G"Mingw Makefiles"` and `mingw32-make` it started building, but after a while this error hapenned:

```
<...>
[  5%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/CTagsEmitter.cpp.obj
[  5%] Built target obj.llvm-tblgen
[  5%] Linking CXX executable ..\..\bin\llvm-tblgen.exe
../../lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Threading.cpp.obj): In function `IterateProcInfo<getProcessorGroups()::<lambda()>::<lambda(SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX*)> >':
C:/.../llvm-12.0.0.src/lib/Support/Windows/Threading.inc:143: undefined reference to `_imp__GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx@12'
C:/.../llvm-12.0.0.src/lib/Support/Windows/Threading.inc:148: undefined reference to `_imp__GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx@12'
C:/.../llvm-12.0.0.src/lib/Support/Windows/Threading.inc:143: undefined reference to `_imp__GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx@12'
C:/.../llvm-12.0.0.src/lib/Support/Windows/Threading.inc:148: undefined reference to `_imp__GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx@12'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\build.make:192: bin/llvm-tblgen.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:9445: utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/llvm-tblgen.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:155: all] Error 2
```

I would guess that the error is linked with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26405420/w64-mingw-llvmsupport-a-undefined-reference-to-imp), and there is/are some missing libraries and adding those using `-D"CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-l..."` would fix the error. But what are those libraries? I got the error at 5% and there might be more libraries that I need to link (and the 5% already took pretty long time, so I don't want to wait for 50% to find out that there was an error).
So, What libraries do I need to link LLVM with?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getlogicalprocessorinformationex

Comment: @AlanBirtles What library is it in? I tried adding `-D"CMAKE_CXX_F:AGS=-lkernel32"` to cmake, but it still failed at the same place. What should I change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=` is for compiler flags, not linker flags.
Try something like this: `-DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-Wl,--as-needed -lkernel32"`.